# First time working with an API in React - Openweather API - TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api

I've been working on a little Dashboard App, trying to pull the temperature for my city and wanting to display it. I have also searched through a dozen threads with similar problems and it feels like I am close to solving it.

I've used [this](https://dev.to/imshines/a-simple-weather-app-using-react-and-openweathermap-api-10m2) tutorial as a reference.

The main problem is that I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined" error when trying to access `apiData.main.temp` way down in the return. Looking via the console it seems that the temperature value lies within this line but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks a lot in advance! I am trying to learn and I hope I didn't mess up in a stupid way and I am more than happy to be shown the proper ways!

Merci!

This here is the code of the App component:

```
function App() {
    // State
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
    const weatherInCity = "Vienna";

    // API KEY AND URL
    const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${weatherInCity}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`;

    // Side effect
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setApiData(data));
    }, [apiUrl]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="app-item">
                <h1>Temperature</h1>
                <p>{apiData.main.temp}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mutliple ways, using useEffect is one of the way

So here the problem is you are calling an async request, so the response of that is in future within waiting for that time your render has been done with apiData as empty so thats why you get the error, so what you need to do is write another useEffect with array deps as apiData so when its changed you can get the value on the render

```
const [temp, setTemp] = useState(null)
 
useEffect(() => {
   if(!apiData?.main?.temp) return
   setTemp(apiData.main.temp)
   
}, [apiData])
```

in your return

```
<p>{temp && temp}</p>
```

Even you can add a ternary check and show text loading and once loaded api success you can access apiData?.main?.temp

Comment: if it helped you kindly accept and vote so that will be helpful for future reference :)

Comment: All of these work! Can you elaborate on which of these solutions is "best-practice" or the most elegant? Merci!

Comment: I may be not tell which is right one, since these all solutions are not anti-pattern it all are good, usually since you have only one element depend you can use a loading state and show the other parts and keep this informed to that user that its loading so it won't block the entire section.
Also if it helped you  kindly accept and vote so that will be helpful for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

On your first render cycle, apiData is simply {} because that's how you initialized it in setState. This is before the API gets called. React tries to render your component but can't because it doens't have the data. Don't assume you've already fetched data when rendering the component, you should check first. So something like:

```js
return(
   apiData.main ? ...yourComponentHere : <div>...Loading</div>
)
```

This can be done better, obviously, with loading spinners, handling for timeouts etc but this is the root of your problem.

EDIT: If you want an elegant way to handle rendering while data is fetching you can read up on [suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html).

Comment: Thank you! This worked super. Merci as well for the reading material!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your HTML renders before receiving data,
in your return replace following line

```
                <p>{apiData.main.temp}</p>
```

with this

```
                <p>{(apiData.main || {}).temp || 'loading temp...'}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `apiData` as an empty object, so accessing `apiData.main.temp` on first render will already fail as `apiData.main` is `undefined` at that point and therefore has not property `temp`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thank you.